# How to design prism EventAggregator?

Tags: prism

> Pattern of pub-sub events is that the
>   publisher should not know or care if
>   there are any subscribers out there,
>   nor should it care what the
>   subscribers do if they are there (from
>   [Brian Noyes'
>   blog](http://briannoyes.net/2009/09/05/SupportingGracefulShutdownAndSavingOnCloseFromAWPFPrismApp.aspx))

What are the best practices to using EventAggregator in Prism? Currently I have few modules which are loosely coupled and work independently. These modules use EventAggregator to communicate to other modules. As the application grows I'm confused on how to document my code. There could be many modules publishing Events and many others subscribing to it as Brian puts neither of them knows what other does exactly. When creating a new module how do I make sure they are subscribed to some XYZ event without breaking the loosely coupled structure?

How do I represent a module using EventAggregator visually (some kind of diagrams)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a lot of questions in your post that can be answered "it depends on your application," but I'll try to answer some of them.

One thing that I see most often with EventAggregator is *abuse*.  Many people use EventAggregator in a way that makes both the publisher and subscriber dependent on each other.  This brings me to my first bit of advise:

**Never assume there are any subscibers to an event.**

EventAggregator is useful for publishing events other views *might* be interested in.  For example, in our application we allow a user to change someone's name.  This name might be displayed on other views already open in the application (we have a tabbed UI). Our use case was we wanted to have those UIs update when the name was changed, so we published a "UserDataChanged" event so that open views could subscribe and refresh their data appropriately, but if no views that were open were interested in this data, no subscribers were notified.

**Favor .NET Events over EventAggregator events where appropriate**

Another mistake I see frequently is a business process that is implemented using EventAggregator where data is sent to a central party and then that party replies, all using EventAggregator.  This is leads to some side-effects you'd likely want to avoid.

A variation on that I see a lot is communication from a parent view to a sub-view, or vice-versa.  Something like "TreeItemChecked" or "ListViewItemSelected".  This is a situation where traditional .NET Events would be used, but an author decided that if they have a hammer (EventAggregator), everything (Events) looks like a nail.

---

You asked about **modeling the EventAggregator** and I would say this: the EventAggregator is only special in that it allows for decoupling and doesn't create strong references to events (avoiding memory leaks, etc).  Other than that, **it's really just a very slight variation of the [Observer Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/patterns/patternobserver.aspx)**.  However you are modeling Observers is how you would model the EventAggregator in whatever type of diagram you are trying to create.

As to your question about **making sure some module or another is subscribed to an event**: ***you don't***.  If you need to ensure there are subscribers, you should not use the EventAggregator.  In these cases I would recommend a service running in your application that modules can grab from your container and use or other similar thing.

The thing to keep in mind about your modules is that you should be able to completely remove one and the rest of your application *functions normally*.  If this is not the case, you either have a module dependency (best to be avoided, but understandable), or dependent modules should be combined into one.

Comment: Great piece of advice. Thank you.